# Resources for understanding Javascript used for Redux and Thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am doing a tutorial on React with Redux and Thunk and am having trouble understanding how some of the props are being sent to the different components. I think I understanding how the Flux Architecture in general is working, but the code itself filled with functions returning other functions and other syntax that is making my head spin. How the dispatcher is working for example is a complete mystery to me. Googling around I have read that this is a very "functional programming" approach to doing things in react. Can anyone point me to some resources to get up to speed with the type of Javascript used for Redux and Thunk?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some links,

1. [Redux.org](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started)
2. [React-redux tutorial for beginners](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/redux/)
3. [Redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)